# Code First CTP5 Many To Many Binding

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I have been using the Code First approach for the Entity Framework. I have an Event class, a Band class and a EventBands class which maps the many to many relationship. The Code First approach worked fine (When I didn't have the EventBands class) but then I decided I wanted the many to many table to store additional values. Now I get this error message:

System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'EventBands' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: The EntitySet EventBands is based on type EventBands that has no keys defined.

It obvious what the error message means. However the resolution isn't so obvious. I think I have to override the model binding method but I am not entirely sure how to map keys with this approach.

Any help would be appreciated, I have included the classes in question below.

Thanks in advance,

Jon

Event:

```
#region Properties
    private int eventId;
    public int EventId
    {
        get
        {
            return eventId;
        }
        set
        {
            eventId = value;
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime startDatetime;
    public DateTime StartDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return startDatetime;
        }
        set
        {
            startDatetime = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime endDatetime;
    public DateTime EndDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return endDatetime;
        }
        set
        {
            endDatetime = value;
        }
    }

    private int venueUserId;
    public int VenueUserId
    {
        get { return venueUserId; }
        set { venueUserId = value; }
    }

    public virtual Venue Venue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<EventReview> Reviews
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<EventBands> EventBands
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Fan> Attendees
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Event()
    {
        EventBands = new HashSet<EventBands>();
        Attendees = new HashSet<Fan>();
        StartDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        EndDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
    }
    #endregion
```

Band:

```
public class Band : PostableUser
{
    #region Properties
    private int genreGenreId;
    public int GenreGenreId
    {
        get { return genreGenreId; }
        set { genreGenreId = value; }
    }

    public virtual Genre Genre
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<BandReview> Reviews
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<EventBands> EventBands
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Band()
    {
        EventBands = new HashSet<EventBands>();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

EventBands

```
#region Properties
    private int eventEventId;
    public int EventEventId
    {
        get { return eventEventId; }
        set { eventEventId = value; }
    }

    public virtual Event Event
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private int bandUserId;
    public int BandUserId
    {
        get { return bandUserId; }
        set { bandUserId = value; }
    }

    public virtual Band Band
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private DateTime startDateTime;
    public DateTime StartDateTime
    {
        get { return startDateTime; }
        set { startDateTime = value; }
    }

    private DateTime endDateTime;
    public DateTime EndDateTime
    {
        get { return endDateTime; }
        set { endDateTime = value; }
    }
    #endregion
```

BandUserId is inherited from the User base class.

Comment: Please show your full object model. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working in the end by overriding the OnModelCreating method in my DataContext class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AlbumConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BandConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommentConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CountryConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CountyConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EventBandsConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EventFansConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EventConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FanConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GenreConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PostConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RecordLabelConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ReviewConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TrackConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VenueConfiguration());
    }
```

The Configuration classes contain the mappings of the primary, composite keys, foreign keys, and any other properties.

Event Configuration:

```
public class EventConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
{
    public EventConfiguration()
    {
        #region Primary Key
        this.HasKey(x => x.EventId);
        #endregion

        #region Foreign Keys
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Venue)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.VenueId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        this.Property(x => x.Description).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar");
        this.Property(x => x.EndDateTime).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar");
        this.Property(x => x.StartDateTime).IsRequired();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Event Bands Configuration:

```
public class EventBandsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<EventBands>
{
    public EventBandsConfiguration()
    {
        #region Primary Key
        this.HasKey(x => new { x.BandId, x.EventId });
        #endregion

        #region Foreign Keys
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Band)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.BandId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Event)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        this.Property(x => x.StartDateTime).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.EndDateTime).IsRequired();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

User Configuration:

```
public UserConfiguration()
    {
        #region Primary Key
        this.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
        #endregion

        #region Foreign Keys
        this.HasRequired(x => x.City)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CityId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        this.Property(x => x.UserName);
        this.Property(x => x.LoweredUserName);
        this.Property(x => x.ApplicationName);
        this.Property(x => x.Email);
        this.Property(x => x.Comment);
        this.Property(x => x.Password);
        this.Property(x => x.PasswordQuestion);
        this.Property(x => x.PasswordAnswer);
        this.Property(x => x.IsApproved);
        this.Property(x => x.LastActivityDate);
        this.Property(x => x.LastLoginDate);
        this.Property(x => x.LastPasswordChangedDate);
        this.Property(x => x.CreationDate);
        this.Property(x => x.IsOnline);
        this.Property(x => x.IsLockedOut);
        this.Property(x => x.LastLockedOutDate);
        this.Property(x => x.FailedPasswordAttemptCount);
        this.Property(x => x.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart);
        this.Property(x => x.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount);
        this.Property(x => x.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart);
        this.Property(x => x.MobileAlias);
        this.Property(x => x.IsAnonymous);
        this.Property(x => x.Description);
        this.Property(x => x.Website);
        #endregion

        #region Inheritance Mapping
        this.Map<Fan>(x => x.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Fan"))
            .Map<Band>(x => x.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Band"))
            .Map<Venue>(x => x.Requires("UserType").HasValue("Venue"));
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Band Configuration

```
public class BandConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Band>
{
    public BandConfiguration()
    {
        #region Foreign Keys
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Genre)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.GenreId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        #endregion
    }
}
```